# unable to do alt code (alt+11) with send_input

Tags: c++, winapi

What I an trying to do is send the alt code alt+1 which = ☺ with send input. so i have to hold atl, press numpad 1, then let go of alt. Currently when the code runs it does hold the alt button, but has no output into the active window (notepad). I verified sendinput is working with key combos (ctrl+a) work. Num lock is turned on while this program is running. alt+f also works. I think the problem is that it is maybe sending '1' instead of numpad '1', which does not work with alt codes.

```
Sleep(1000 * 3);
INPUT tabinput[4];
tabinput[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
tabinput[0].ki = { VK_LMENU, 0 };
tabinput[1].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
tabinput[1].ki = { VK_NUMPAD1, 0 };
tabinput[2].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
tabinput[2].ki = { VK_NUMPAD1, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP };
tabinput[3].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
tabinput[3].ki = { VK_LMENU, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP };
SendInput(4, tabinput, sizeof(INPUT));
getchar();
```

Comment: can anyone tell me why the downvotes?

Comment: apparently SO frowns upon people saying why they downvote.

Comment: Notice that ☺ is U+263A: WHITE SMILING FACE.

Comment: Why not simply set the text to "☺" (U+263A: WHITE SMILING FACE)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the following code can be used to type unicode chars
using http://www.unicodemap.org/search.asp to find the correct code

```
INPUT tabinput[2];
tabinput[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
tabinput[0].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_UNICODE;
tabinput[0].ki.wVk = 0;
tabinput[0].ki.wScan = 0x00E1; // This is a Bengali unicode character
tabinput[1].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
tabinput[1].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_UNICODE | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
tabinput[1].ki.wVk = 0;
tabinput[1].ki.wScan = 0x00E1; // This is a Bengali unicode character
SendInput(2, tabinput, sizeof(INPUT));
```

Comment: Hm... I hope you aren't saying that U+00E1 is a Bengali character, because U+00E1 is simply á (LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH ACUTE). The Bengali characters have much higher codepoints (of course).

Comment: In this example, the correct codepoint to use for `☺` is U+263A: `ki.wScan = 0x263A;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Unicode characters directly. If code point is less than `0xFFFF` use:

```
input.ki.wScan = L'☺';
```

Some characters have code point greater than `0xFFFF`, they require two key strokes for each code point, in which case use a wide string to handle it:

```
const wchar_t *buf = L"বাংলা ☺  Abc";

std::vector<INPUT> vec;
for(size_t i = 0, len = wcslen(buf); i < len; i++)
{
    INPUT input = { 0 };
    input.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    input.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_UNICODE;
    input.ki.wScan = buf[i];
    vec.push_back(input);

    input.ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    vec.push_back(input);
}

SendInput(vec.size(), vec.data(), sizeof(INPUT));
```